# find -name "*.xyz" -o -name "*.abc" -exec to Execute on all found files, not just the last suffix specified

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to run

```
find ./ -name "*.xyz" -o -name "*.abc" -exec cp {} /path/i/want/to/copy/to
```

In reality it's a larger list of name extensions but I don't know that matters for this example.  Basically I'd like to copy all those found to another /path/i/want/to/copy/to.  However it seems to only be executing the last -name test in the list.

If I remove the -exec portion all the variations of files I expect to be found are printed out.

How do I get it to pass the full complement of files found to -exec?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`find` works by evaluating the expressions you give it until it can determine the truth value (true or false) of the entire expression. In your case, you're essentially doing the following, since by default it ANDs the expressions together.

```
-name "*.xyz" OR ( -name "*.abc" AND -exec ... )
```

Quoth the man page:

> GNU find searches
> the directory tree rooted at each given file  name  by  evaluating  the
> given  expression  from left to right, according to the rules of precedence (see section OPERATORS), until the outcome    is  known  (the  left
> hand  side  is  false  for and operations, true for or), at which point
> find moves on to the next file name.

That means that if the name matches `*.xyz`, it won't even try to check the latter `-name` test or `-exec`, since it's already true.

What you want to do is enforce precedence, which you can do with parentheses. Annoyingly, you also need to use backslashes to escape them on the shell:

```
find ./ \( -name "*.xyz" -o -name "*.abc" \) -exec cp {} /path/i/want/to/copy/to \;
```

Comment: `-exec cp -t dir {} +` might be more efficient

Comment: I think you mean "backslashes"

Comment: Space is important before and after parentheses otherwise you will get this error "find: paths must precede expression: (-name"

Answer (score 17):

More usable than Jaypal's solution would maybe be:

```
   find ./ -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|png\)" -exec cp {} /path/to
```

Comment: Yep, your solution is better. I will go ahead and delete mine. +1

Comment: more powerful find usage

Answer (score 8):

```
find . \( -name "*.xyz" -o -name "*.abc" \) -exec cp {} /path/i/want/to/copy/to \;
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I gave accepted to Dan Fego as you seemed tied with his in answer time and his was more informative.

Answer (score -3):

It may work:

```
find ./ -name "*.{xyz,abc}" -exec cp {} /path/i/want/to/copy/to
```

Comment: From `man find`: Braces are not recognised as being special, despite the fact that some shells including Bash imbue braces with a special  meaning  in shell patterns.