# Find command, linux

Tags: linux, find, command

```
find -type f -name "*.avi" -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
find -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
```

How to combine these two commands?
1. Either by combining both search terms in one command or 2. Both commands adding output to one file. Hope it's clear what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find -type f \( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mp4" \) -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887972/find-name-xyz-o-name-abc-exec-to-execute-on-all-found-files-not-jus) for explanation

Answer (score 0):

For Both commands adding output to one file .You Can do:

```
find -type f -name "*.avi," -exec md5sum {} + >> checklist.chk
find -type f -name "*.mp4," -exec md5sum {} + >> checklist.chk
```

Output file will have results of first command first and then the results of second command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -o option as OR operator in commands.
So, you can do it like this.

```
find -type f -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mp4" -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
```